# dynamically change the value of the ng-init with ng-repeat simultaneously with id

Tags: angularjs

```
<div class="rightside-table-container">

    <div ng-repeat="d in organiser" ng-init="get_org_dtls(d.ref_No)"
        id="cr-upper-div">
        <div class="row" id="cr-upperdiv-firstrow">
            <table class="table" id="cr-tableclass">
                <tbody id="upperdiv-table-tbody">
                    <a href="#">
                        <tr id="cr-upperdiv-firsttr">
                            <td colspan="3">{{d.organiser_Name}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </a>
                    <tr id="cr-upperdiv-secondtr">
                        <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
                            data-toggle="tooltip" title="Billed" id="cr-upperdiv-firsttd"><span>8</span></td>
                        <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
                            data-toggle="tooltip" title="On Hold" id="cr-upperdiv-secondtd">7</td>
                        <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
                            data-toggle="tooltip" title="Void Bill" id="cr-upperdiv-thirdtd">2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="cr-upperdiv-thirdtr">

                        <td ng-repeat="od in organiser_dtls_data"
                            ng-if="od.organiser_Code==d.ref_No"><md-button
                                ng-click="showCashregister($event)"
                                class="md-raised md-primary org_dtls_btn">

                            <div class="organiser_dtls_container md-ink-ripple">

                                <div class="org_head">
                                    <p class="org_title">{{od.organiser_Details_Name}}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="org_mid">
                                    <div class="org_loc">
                                        <p class="org_loc_title">{{od.organiserLocation.organiser_Location_Name}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="org_capacity">
                                        <p class="org_cap_title">{{od.organiser_Capacity}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="org_status">
                                    <p class="org_status_title">Reserved</p>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            </md-button></td>


                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="cr-upperdiv-secondrow">
            <div class="merge" id="cr-mergeclass">
                <div class="merge-icon">
                    <img class="Centered" src="/images/mergew.png" height="20px"
                        width="20px" />
                </div>
                <div class="merge-text">
                    <span>Merge</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="split" id="cr-splitclass">
                <div class="merge-icon">
                    <img class="Centered" src="/images/splitw.png" height="20px"
                        width="20px" />
                </div>
                <div class="merge-text">
                    <span>Split</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: **Describe the problem.** Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: The [ng-init directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. You should use [Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) or [Controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope.